# Generic classes in "frameworkname"-Swift.h causes "Type name requires a specifier or qualifier" error in Xcode 6.3

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, xcode6.3

I updated to Xcode 6.3, and I had two separate projects (one is a framework) in my workspace. Now, Xcode autogenerated this "frameworkname"-Swift.h header file, but when I had a generic class as a property, it produces the following lines:

```
@class Presentation;
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC13BusinessLogic31MeetupDetailViewControllerModel")
@interface MeetupDetailViewControllerModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) /* RsvpStore<Rsvp> */ anRsvpStore;
@end
```

There is no equialent to gerenics in Objective-c, so how can I solve this problem?

I found that I can solve the problem if I set the type to NSObject like:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSObject * __nonnull anRsvpStore;
```

but with every build, this file is recreated to the same wrong version. So how can I force this build to set the type of this generic to NSObject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could stop creating this compatibility header by setting in `Build Settings` -> `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` -> `Intall Objective-C Compatibility Header` to `No`.

Since I've not written Objective-C code in my project, there is no problem with this option, but this is rather a workaround than a solution for generics in the compatibility header.

**Another workaround** is if you mark your properties with `private`, then they won't appear in the compatibility header.

**Swift 2.0 update**

> A new
>   @nonobjc
>   attribute is introduced to selectively suppress ObjC export for instance members that would 
>   otherwise be
>   @objc
>   . (16763754)
>   Blockquote

Not tested, but this looks like a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved in #1873 https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1873

If you don't need to use swift in objc,just set **Intall Objective-C Compatibility Header** to No.

If you need to use swift in objc,you have to edited the -Swift.h and set it in **Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name**